# Can I deploy pl/sql in jenkins without building it

Tags: java, jenkins, plsql, bitbucket

we have a PL/SQL code and we need that to be available on bit-bucket.And we want the code to be deployed through Jenkins without building it.can i create a separate project on Jenkins for the PL/SQL to deploy it but not to build it?

Comment: as far as i know you can't

Comment: hi jason.Thank you for the reply. Jenkins doesn't support PL/SQL code? or you have another reason